# Why does my date object have methods for Sunday and Monday, but not the other days of the week?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

Can anyone explain the following behavior?

```
date = Date.today
# => Sat, 23 Apr 2016
date.sunday
# => Sun, 24 Apr 2016
date.monday
# => Mon, 18 Apr 2016
date.tuesday
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `tuesday' for Sat, 23 Apr 2016:Date
Did you mean?  tuesday?
```

Comment: They're just not defined. Not sure what sort of answer you're looking for.

Comment: It seems weird that a subset of the days of the week are available, but most aren't. I want to know why those two specifically are and the rest aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it is not that frequent that you want to refer to a certain day in the middle of a week. If you can get the beginning of a week, then getting the other days of the week is easy. And probably `sunday` and `monday` would suffice under any locale. I have not seen any country/culture that has anything other than sunday or monday as the beginning of a week.